# Pivoting equivalent in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following statement in SQL Server where I am using `pivot`:

```
Select YR, [1] As Beginning, [2] As Inter, [3] As Advanced, [4] As AdvHigh,Campus
From    
    (Select YR, Rating, StudentId, Campus 
        from mytable
        Where YR = '2014'
    ) As Data
    PIVOT   (Count(StudentId)
            For Rating IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
    ) As Pvt
```

Now I am trying to write the same query in Postgresql (I am a newbie to postgresql). I have looked at **tablefunc** but am not exactly sure how to use it yet.

Any help will be great!

Comment: Can you provide an SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with example input and the example output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with `tablefunc` in postgresql but you can replicate a `PIVOT` by using a `CASE` expression with an aggregate function:

```
Select YR, 
  sum(case when ListeningProfRating = 1 then 1 else 0 end) As Begining,
  sum(case when ListeningProfRating = 2 then 1 else 0 end) As Inter,
  sum(case when ListeningProfRating = 3 then 1 else 0 end) As Advanced,
  sum(case when ListeningProfRating = 4 then 1 else 0 end) As AdvHigh
  Campus 
from mytable
Where YR = '2014' 
  AND ListeningScoreCode IN('S', 'B')
group by yr, campus
```

Comment: hi...thank you for the solution. it worked great. is there a way we could use crosstab here for the pivot?

Comment: @crozzfire Yes, but I'm not familiar with that syntax - see this question/answer -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query